# strstr in array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm have code that needs to check if a particular string that will vary in length each time is within a string in an array that will also vary in length each time.

I can get it to check if text is in a particular string using 'strstr' and I can check if a string is in and array using 'in_array' but I can't seem to connect the two.

To put it as simple as I can:

```
$array = array([0]=>'12345',[1]=>'67890');
if(in_array(strstr(3,$array)))
= true
or
= 0 (being the key)
```

(obviously this wouldn't work but hopefully it helps show what I'm trying to do)

I have considered breaking up the array into parts and comparing each one individually that way but I'm concerned that with the size of the array and the number of times it will have to completed this operation in one run that it could cause speed issues.  Also, if there is a cleaner way anyone can think of it would be much better all round.

Comment: Would you mind posting an example string indicating what exactly you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve it using functional programming in PHP. Since PHP 5.3 it has been much improved. However, I have to admit, I think it iterates over the whole array even if the element has been found. The iterative solution (see below) could stop.

The functional solution might also look a bit complicated, so if you do not understand it, just use the iterative one below ;) I just wrote it, because I think functional is often be elegant for array tasks.

```
<?php

function checkIfInArrayString($array, $needle) {
    $found = array_reduce($arr, function($isFound, $value) use ($needle) {
        return $isFound || false !== strpos($value, $needle);
    }, false);

    return $found;
}

$arr = array(
    'foo',
    'my',
    'test'
);

var_dump(checkIfInArrayString($arr, 'oo'));
var_dump(checkIfInArrayString($arr, 'ooo'));
```

This is the iterative solution (untested) for the same problem:

```
function checkIfInArrayString($array, $searchingFor) {
    foreach ($array as $element) {
        if (strpos($element, $searchingFor) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I used `strpos` instead of `strstr`, because it’s recommended by the PHP documentation when you only need to know if a string is withing another. `strpos` returns less information and thus has a lighter implementation.

Comment: I don't fully understand the first chunk of code but the second is similar to what I was thinking in regards breaking it up.  I was just concerned about speed issues with it.  I would also be interested in getting the key from the array if possible.  Would this be the best approach to do this?

Comment: Yes, I think the second approach is the fastest one. At least I think you want to search for substrings (so e.g. `o` in `foo` shall be found) and not only beginnings of strings? If it was only the beginning of strings **and** you had a sorted array, you could use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search), but in your case you’ll best run over the whole array if it’s only one time. If you have to search it hundreds of times larger data structures might be interesting (e.g. [suffix trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)).

Comment: If you know Big-O-notation, this solution runs in O(n). So it’s linear in size of your input. Creating a suffix tree also costs O(n) or O(n^2) if it’s not the best solution. And it can be queried in O(|Sigma| * m) where Sigma is the alphabet (so e.g. |Sigma| = 26) and m is the length of your search string (e.g. 3 for `foo`). So it’s quite fast if you query your array very, very often. Generalized suffix trees can also give you the index of the matching array element, I think, but it’s really an advanced topic.

Comment: I don't think I've even heard of big o notation

Comment: No problem, the main idea is: If you only query your large array rarely, take the iterative search with breaking when you found the element. If you query the same array hundreds of times (with different search strings), use a more elaborate data structure (e.g. suffix tree) which requires precalculation, but then querying is faster. But it really depends on the size of the array. 100 elements will not be a problem for the iterative solution, 100.000 might be a problem. Best try it.

Comment: I don't think it would go much further than 400 max so might stick with the more straight forward option but it's good to know theres even more I don't know how to do with this coding milarky

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is very old, but now there is `preg_grep()`

```
$array = array([0]=>'12345',[1]=>'67890');
$result = preg_grep('/3/',$array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain from your question if this is what you're trying to do, but it looks like a simple preg_match() would solve your problem. Lets say you're looking for the string "hello world" contained within the strings "`somethingsomething`"...`hello world`..."`somethingelse`".

You would simply use

```
preg_match(/somethingsomething(.*)hello world(.*)somethingelse/, $haystack); //return 1 if found
```

A bit cleaner of an example: if you were looking for the string "`str`" between two occurrences of `::`

```
preg_match(/::(.*)str(.*)::/, $haystack); //if (found) return 1; 
                                          //if (!found) return 0; 
                                          //if (err) return false;

$multiple_occurences = /::(.*)(str)(.*)::/;
$single_occurence    = /::(.*)str(.*)::/;
```

I hope this makes it a bit more clear. If you have any questions about the preg_match() method, the documentation is quite helpful: [preg_match() Documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
            if ( in_array("search string", $array) ) echo "search string is in the array";
```

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the original problem, some explanation would help a lot in understanding the method you've used and how it works